# Directory in tmp over 90 days old | permission denied for root | all question marks for read and write | user can see root owns dir

Tags: bash, security, permissions, read-write, tmp

I am trying to remove a file in my /tmp dir I have just been made aware of due to Lynis.

One security check suggested I remove all files in tmp over 90 days old.

I have a cronjob now:

`find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \; > "$report_path" 2>"$error_log"`

Every error log contains this.

`/bin/find: ‘/tmp/.mount_jetbrayU5cHz’: Permission denied`

This is what the file looks like to root (`whoami` returns root - both `sudo su` and `su`):

`d?????????  ? ?       ?        ?            ? .mount_jetbrayU5cHz`

This what the file looks like to my user:

`drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root       0 Jun  2 20:54 .mount_jetbrayU5cHz`

I have also run the following commands (in root):

`lsattr: Permission denied while trying to stat .mount_jetbrayU5cHz`

`ls: cannot access '/tmp/.mount_jetbrayU5cHz': Permission denied`

`chmod: cannot access '.mount_jetbrayU5cHz': Permission denied`

`cd: permission denied: .mount_jetbrayU5cHz`

For some reason remove's arguments are also ignored in relation to this directory:

```
$ rm -rf .mount_jetbrayU5cHz

rm: cannot remove '.mount_jetbrayU5cHz': Is a directory
```

I have seen some other posts related to question marks and tmp but they included this happening to the user, not the root, and if it was root then it was a protected symlink - there was also a thread with a mounted filesystem and some directories created by automatic processes. This looks to be created by jetbrains but it looks like a regular directory to me.

I am not overly concerned about removing this dir as it's not getting in the way of anything, its just very odd and I am wondering if it is part of a bigger problem.

Any advice is appreciated.

edit: I am currently running Arch

edit: I'm able to confirm this doesn't persist through reboot and is now. `.mount_jetbrahVDgXi`

Everything about this files behaviour is strange as the error came  across when running a command for files over 90 days old.

Wondering why there are no threads about this with Jetbrains.

Kind of concerning that they can make a directory out of root's control.

Comment: Do you have SELinux or something similar enabled?

Comment: Hi jiwopene, I don't have SELinux (or AppArmor) installed, cheers